# Elasticsearch 2.x must_not can not filter match data, but it working fine in 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine

Elasticsearch 2.x and 5.x all fine with bool->must->match, but must_not no working with Elasticsearch 2.x. If replace term with match, and specify a precise condition, it work well. Is there any way to make must_not and match work in Elasticsearch 2.x, thanks.
The json code:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "match": {
                "subject": "part"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Sorry for this question, I'm a newbie of Elasticsearch, I didn't find my colleague set three sub field for the "subject" in the Es 2.x, I didn't specify the any sub field, so it run with nothing. There is the different setting in two engine.

ES 2.x

```
{
"type": "string",
"index": "no",
"fields": {
    "py": {
        "type": "string",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "analyzer": "pinyin_analyzer"
    },
    "pyfl": {
        "type": "string",
        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
        "analyzer": "pinyin_analyzer_first_letter"
    },
    "raw": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "ik_max_word"
    }
}
```

}

ES 5.x

```
{
"type": "text",
"fields": {
    "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
    }
}
```

It work fine with this json

```
    {
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must_not": {
            "match": {
                "subject.raw": "part"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: You need to provide more details: the mapping of the index, sample data and what documents don't match and should.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thanks for you answer, I find the problem is the field define, I will update my question, thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think problem not with version . I am using version  1.7 .

Problem in your json ,validate with http://jsonlint.com/ .
try this :-

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must_not" : {
        "match" : { "subject" : "part" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I found the problem is the field define. My colleague  set three sub field with different analyzer, I didn't specify the sub field. I'm a newbie with Elasticsearch, sorry. Q_Q.

Comment: No problem . It happens for all  when something new .